# cannot perform memory profiling as instructed

Tags: python, ipython

I am following http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling/ exactly to trying to do memory profiling, but when I started ipython, I got the error... Any idea? Thanks

```
AttributeError: 'TerminalInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'define_magic'
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `ipython_config.py` file to use the following may fix it.

`c.TerminalIPythonApp.extensions = [
    'line_profiler',
    'memory_profiler',
]
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = [
    'line_profiler',
    'memory_profiler',
]`

Note the removal of the `_ext` for each extension.